# How to access microphone from a webapp on VM

Tags: virtual-machine

Currently, I'm working on an assignment that necessitates running Node-RED on a virtual machine. Fortunately, I was able to successfully run it on an Azure VM. However, upon launching the web app, the browser detected it as unsecured, resulting in the blocking of my app's microphone permission. Despite attempting to change the permission status in Chrome settings, I have been unable to do so.

Comment: Post the error detecting it being insecure.  I am just guessing you are trying to connect to something via HTTP and you need an SSL for it to access HTTPS connections to ensure encrypted secure status.